# Rails times comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to compare two dates:
One date is taken form a table, `created_at` column and the other one is taken from (i don't know, server time, or client time).

So is it ok to compare them like this?

```
t.strftime("%Y-%d-%m") == Time.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

Where `t` is the table row.create_at.

And now about, the time that my `t` will be compared with, from where is Time.now taken from my computer, or from the server?

If is taken from my computer, how can I use the server time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Rails know that your time information is stored as UTC in the database it will convert any time you give it to UTC.

I think we should use

```
t.strftime("%Y-%d-%m") == Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

at the place of

```
t.strftime("%Y-%d-%m") == Time.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

Just be sure to never construct the query string by hand and always use Time.zone.now as the base and you should be safe.

For more info, go through [working with time zones](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 2):

This comparison will work as expected because you are converting time to string and then comparing strings. I usually convert to integer for comparison but since you are comparing dates you would need to convert time objects to date object first.

Ruby is executed on the server so `Time.now` is always server time. If you want to compare with utc time use `Time.current`